# When calculating work in a line integral is the work done time independent?

Tags: classical-mechanics, work, integration

The paramaterization of a curve when calculating the line integral is independent of the paramterization, it depends on path taken in the curve. My intuition is failing me, since it was said that by paramaterizing you can make the path progress faster or slower.

That is why I ask the question but on a more fundamental note I cannot see why the paramaterization makes no difference. Does it not have to match the curve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work done is path independent if the force is a conservative force, meaning there is a potential scalar function (this is all in classical physics) whose negative gradient is the force. Examples are electrical and gravitational forces in vacuum. Examples of non-conservative forces are friction (i.e., anything that dissipates energy into heat) as well as time dependent potentials.

The condition for conservative forces ias equivalent to the work done being the different in potential between the two point (start and finish), and so obviously path independent. It is also equivalent to zero work done if you start and end in the same place, and to the curl of the force is zero. All those are equivalent, and if the force is not so it is non-conservative.

See the definition, examples and math in the Wikipedia article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force. It is the basis for how to introduce a potential energy, and the conservation of potential plus kinetic energy. First year physics in college with teach this typically, maybe some advanced physics in HS.